# Convert .ai to another kind of vector graphics format(like .eps or .svg) using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick, adobe, imagemagick-convert

I have a folder with many .ai files and i need to get copy of this files but with .eps format. How to convert .ai files to .eps files im my .NET project? I'm trying to use ImageMagick, but output file is a  rasterized version of input file. How can i get vector file in output?

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("d:\\file.eps"))
            {
                image.Write("d:\\file.ai"); 
            }
```

I get rasterized version of input file, but i need vector file.

Comment: Imagemagick uses Ghostscript to read AI/PDF/PS/EPS and always rasterizes. So Imagemagick is not the tool to use for that activity if you want vector results.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Probably you know any tool i can use in my task?

Comment: No, sorry, I do not know of any tool that will do that. Have you searched Google?